# Compare two different URL directories in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url, comparison

I want to pull out 2 directories only in Google Analytics to compare them. Can we do that? What is the proper code?

| `Source / Medium` | `Matching RegEx` | `^(bing / cpc | adcenter / cpc)$`

This does not work. I am trying to pull out `bing / cpc` and `adcenter / cpc` and compare only these two on one screen.

Comment: When you say "compare them" do you mean that you want to see the stats for the two directories side by side?  Or do you mean that you want to see the combined stats for these two directories compared to the rest of your site?

Comment: Where are you trying to put your regular expression?  Is this to create an advanced segment, or to create a filter, or something else?

Comment: You have spaces in your regular expression around the slash that separates directories.   I'm not sure if that was how you tried to put it into Google Analytics, or if that was because you didn't know how to use code formatting asking your question here.  Did you actually try `bing/cpc` as opposed to `bing / cpc` in GA?

Comment: When you say "This does not work" what do you mean?   Does it not match either directory?  Or does it not show you the two in a side by side comparison like you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do this, I would use this approach -

1. Create two segments where Source/Medium equals bing/cpc and adcenter/cpc
2. Compare the two segments

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you compare two segments?

Comment: This is Google Analytics, you can choose to add multiple segments in the bar at the top (link - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123906?hl=en)